# iCarousel in swift version 1.2 error (candidate is not Objc but protocol requires it)

Tags: objective-c, swift, icarousel

I get the following error in swift 1.2 : **'RootViewController' does not conform to protocol 'iCarouselDataSource'**

In the below class, when I tryed to implement the third party library iCarousel:

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController,iCarouselDataSource,iCarouselDelegate
{...}
```

The auto-fix tool puts an @objc mark in this method that conform the protocol:

```
@objc func carousel(carousel: iCarousel!, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, var reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView?
{}
```

But then another error appears :  **Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 3 cannot be represented in Objective-C**

I appreciate any help or clue, thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove var from reusingView, ex:

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel!, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView! {
    var newView = view
    if newView == nil {
        //create new view
    }
    //update data
    return newView
}
```